# how to test html code of a big asp.net website

Tags: html

i want to test a big asp.net website through Visual studio. are it is possible. are i need any other tool. if yes then tell me the name of them.

my means testing to "HTML code". means there is no problem in html code and they written in standard way

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Firefox you install the HTML Validator or Total Validator add ons.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Opera, just right-click your page in the browser and you will see something like "Validate source" on the menu.

Or else, you can use the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) at w3.org. There, you can validate HTML by URL, file upload or by direct input.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is online visit http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/ and run a recursive validation